# How to solve unknown host name error using FTP Cmd?

Tags: ftp

In cmd prompt i tried ftp ftp.(Computer Name)that is local area network but it shows unknown host name error.

Comment: There needs to be an FTP server running on the target machine before you can access it.

Comment: please explain clearly

Answer (score 2):

This is a DNS lookup issue - you shouldn't prefix with "ftp."

Just run "ftp computername".

You can also test this by trying to ping the machine in question: "ping ftp.computername" will fail to resolve (with a slightly more meaningful message than the FTP client gives), whereas "ping computername" will respond to ping (unless security software is preventing this).

Comment: it shows could not find the host error

Comment: Make sure your FTP server software is able to respond. You can verify this by running "telnet computername 21" (turns out telnet is not enabled by default: http://www.fettesps.com/windows-7-enable-telnet/). Also make sure your FTP server is setup to use port 21 (the default), or else you'll have to specify the port when you run ftp.

Comment: On top of that, double check you Advanced Fire wall ruleset, or just add INBOUND/OUTBOUND rules on FTP program and TCP/UDP port on which you will communicate with FTP server..

Try out FileZilla through your script just to see if it does work
https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways: the interactive way and the other alternative. For the first, the command syntax is as the following. First launch the dos prompt. At the MSDOS prompt write:

```
ftp
```

you get the ftp prompt

```
ftp>
```

now write the command to open the connection:

```
open website.subdomain.ext
```

Notice: don't use the protocol nor the ftp. string: the command needs just **website.subdomain.ext**

Now you will be prompted to type the user

and then the password.

If all is wrote right you will be able to type ftp commands like **ls** or **send** ecc...

Alternatively you can write directly at the DOS prompt

```
ftp website.subdomain.ext
```

you will be prompted into ftp command prompt for username then for the password

for further help write

```
help ftp
```

at the ms dos prompt